# Gin-Gonic v1.4.0: ctx.FullPath() missing

Tags: go, go-gin

In the previous version of Gin, I was using [ctx.FullPath()](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.FullPath) function to log trace metrics to Stackdriver. The newer 1.4.0 version seems to be missing this function. What alternate option do I have?

Comment: I found v1.4.0 is not newer. fullpath was added on 26 May, v1.4.0 was released on 8 May.

Answer (score 1):

v1.4.0 does not have `fullPath`, it was added later. You can add a later commit to your Go module. To add the commit where `fullPath` was added, use:

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin@35e33d3638f9b5a1246dd9c72a99740f5ad4b43b`
```